# $_GETにより取得したURLの値が次ページのURLのパラメータの値として渡らない。

Tags: php

あるページのURLのパラメータを`$_GET`で取得して、その値を次ページのURLのパラメータに使用する設定にしたいと考え、以下の様に①php内でパラメータの値を`$_GET`で取得した場合と、②php内でパラメータの値を手入力した場合で試しました。

①、②ともphpの`var_dump($product_id);`でhtmlで表示される結果はstring(4) "1434"なのですが、次ページに推移した際に②ではURLのパラメータに値が表示されるのに対して、①は表示されません。

なぜなのでしょうか。①の`$_GET['product_id']`で取得した値がhtmlではstring(4) "1434"と表示されているものの、②の手入力のものとは違い、実際は空だからなのでしょうか。

次ページに推移し、URLのパラメータを設定するプログラムはこの`$product_id`を使用いたしますが、②が機能している以上、今回の問題に関係していないので省略致します。

①も②の様に推移先URLのパラメータで`product_id`の値を表示させたいのですが、解決策、打開策などご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

①php内でパラメータの値を`$_GET`で取得した場合

元のURL
www.example.com/cart/?product_id=1434

phpファイル内

```
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];       
var_dump($product_id);
```

htmlの表示：string(4) "1434"

推移したURL
www.example.com/shopping/?product_id

②php内でパラメータの値を手入力した場合

元のURL
www.example.com/cart/?product_id=1434

phpファイル内

```
$product_id = '1434';       
var_dump($product_id);
```

htmlの表示：string(4) "1434"

推移したURL
www.example.com/shopping/?product_id=1434

Comment: 可能性としては途中で変数がリセットされてしまっていたり、参照が変わっている可能性があります。「同じphpファイル内にあるその下の記述では」とありますが、可能であるならば問題が発生している箇所までプログラムを追記いただくことは可能ですか？

Comment: `$_GET['product_id']`の確認はされているようですが、`$product_id`はどのように確認されましたか？代入直後に`print`しました？もしそうでないのであれば、処理途中で他の値で代入したなどで消失している可能性があると思います。その場合はkeitaro_soさんの仰るように問題が発生している箇所までの処理を記述いただかないと問題点が分かりません。

Comment: 皆様、いろいろと試した結果、変更点があり、全く新たに状況説明を書きました。その上で解決策などご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: 代入直後に表示されていることから変数には渡っているように見受けられるのですが、恐らく途中でネームスペースがブッキングしているかなどで代入してしまって値が消えているか、URLを生成して、実際に遷移しているコードで結合失敗しているかだと思います。全文を見せていただかなければ分からないのではないかと。

Comment: `cart/`から`shopping/`に対してはどのような形でパラメータを渡している=URLを遷移しているのでしょうか。

Comment: 皆様、ご教授頂き感謝いたします。また、事情により情報提供不足であることをお詫び申し上げます。また一方的で恐縮ですが、次ページ推移プログラムを変更するよりは、この$_GET['product_id']で取得された値が不完全であるということだと思いますが、この値を変換することにより（手入力の情報と同じ状態にすることより）、次ページのURLでもパラメータとして表示させる方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 一度、全てを忘れて地道に1処理ずつ`$product_id`を出力して、どの処理まで保持されているか探ってみては如何でしょうか？、遷移する直前までは値は保持されていますか？、また遷移は`header`で`Location`を書いてますか？

Comment: Myaku様、ご教授頂きまして感謝致します。いろいろと試しておりますが、やはり、ただ単純に_GET['product_id']で取得した$product_idと'1434'と手入力した$product_idを同じ状態にする、つまり、値の取得直後、前者を後者と同じ状態に変換することにより、問題を解決することはできませんでしょうか。